# Scipy Optimize Curve fit not properly fitting with real data

Tags: python, python-3.x, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit a decaying exponential function to real world data. I'm having a problem with aligning the function to the actual data.

Here's my code:

```
def test_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x)*np.sin(c*x)

my_time = np.linspace(0,2.5e-6,25000)
p0 = [60000, 700000, 2841842]

params, params_covariance = curve_fit(test_func, my_time, my_amp,p0)
```

My signal and fitted function
[image: My signal and fitted function]

My question: why doesn't the fitted function start where my data starts increasing in amplitude?

Comment: But it does reproduce your data. The fit function does not know that it has to exclude the plateau in the beginning and start later. You have to define that in `test_func`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the problem is that your function does not take into account that the exponential curve can be shifted. If you include this shift as an additional parameter, the fit will probably converge.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def test_func(x, a, b, c, d):  
    return a*np.exp(-b*(x+d))*np.sin(c*(x+d))

my_time = np.linspace(0,2.5e-6,25000)

#generate fake data
testp0 = [66372, 765189, 2841842, -1.23e-7]
test_amp = test_func(my_time, *testp0)
my_amp = test_func(my_time, *testp0)
my_amp[:2222] = my_amp[2222]

p0 = [600, 700000, 2000, -2e-7]
params, params_covariance = curve_fit(test_func, my_time, test_amp, p0)
print(params)
fit_amp = test_func(my_time, *params)

plt.plot(my_time, my_amp, label="data")
plt.plot(my_time, fit_amp, label="fit")
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Sample output

[image]

Comment: Glad this solved it. Always check if your model is theoretically able to fit your data. By definition, your initial function had to start from [0,0].