# Multi-variable curve fitting

Tags: python, excel, scipy, curve-fitting, polynomial-math

I have a pressure (**P**) vs angle (**B**) multi-data set with each curve obtained at constant diameter (**D**) value. I want to fit a curve to the data as a function of angle and diameter: P(B,D) = Polynomial fit equation.

The data set is quite small, I tried using excel to this but I only get a polynomial fit for angle, I would like to add the diameter as well in the function.

```
P_1 = [2750000,2550000,2450000,2325000,2275000,2250000]
P_2 = [1950000,1750000,1670000,1600000,1550000,1510000]
P_3 = [1230000,1100000,1000000,950000,940000,920000]
B = [20,30,40,50,60,70]
D_1=[.25,.25,.25,.25,.25,.25,.25]
D_2=[.3,.3,.3,.3,.3,.3,.3]
D_3=[.4,.4,.4,.4,.4,.4,.4]
```

If I could get a polynomial fit for each curve as a function of B and D that would be perfect, D is a constant in this case.
[image]

Comment: Step 1: Close Excel. It is only good for the most basic calculations. Step 2: What is the expected function here? You are rather vague in your description. We can fit all kinds of things to all kinds of datasets, but for a finite number of data points, there is an infinite number of functions that fit these data points - and the more complicated these functions are the "better" they fit. So, what is your theoretically expected relationship between angle, diameter, and pressure?

Comment: The expected function for pressure is very complex, consisting of 10 variables, I want to reduce the function for pressure, using only two. This,I am attempting to simplify the expected function. Of course this will introduce error, that’s ok. I will accept a basic fitting function, it doesn’t need to be precise in its expression. A polynomial fit should work generally OK. Unsure how to program it is all with Python/matlab.

Comment: We cannot tell you what kind of function you want to define. Tbh, this looks rather like exponential decay, if I had to guess but as I said - all kinds of functions fit to a finite dataset. The general structure is: define your function, call it with scipy curve fit or another least square algorithm, check if it fits your dataset. Surprisingly, I did not find any polynomial example in my list, so here is just the [latest example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64670453/8881141) to illustrate the approach. `np.polyfit` with `np.polyval` might come in handy, if you expect a polynomial function.